# What does this cable go to?

Tags: usb, cable

I would like to know what this cord goes to?  It has this wrote on it(USB shielded high speed cable 2.0 revision 28AWG/1p+28AWG/2c E119932-1.) Does anyone know what is is for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to include a photo of the cable.

Answer (score 5):

It goes into the box of miscellaneous cables.

What's written on the cable actually describes *only the cable* but doesn't say anything about the connections that are put on it. Basically jt just says "this has the right wires for USB 2.0" – a cable like this could be used just about anywhere USB is used.

But in case you mean [this kind of cable](https://www.ebay.com/itm/273930791412) with a USB type A plug on one end and a wide "RJ45"-ish 10P4C connector on the other end – that's an "APC AP9827" cable used for UPS (uninterruptible power supply) devices made by APC, allowing the UPS to be connected to a computer to monitor its status.

(I'm not sure anybody knows why they didn't use a regular Type B on the other end.)

Answer (score 3):

The description on the cable tells us nothing about what the cable actually is or actually *for*.

The description can be broken down into four parts.

1. "USB shielded high speed cable 2.0 revision"

   - it's a USB cable of some description
2. "28AWG/1p"

   - it has 1 pair of [28AWG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) cores for the USB data twisted pair
3. "28AWG/2c"

   - it has two further 28AWG cores, individual rather than as a twisted pair. These will be the power cores.
4. "E119932-1"

   - Is basically just the [Manufacturer UL number](https://productiq.ulprospector.com/en/profile/3049/avlv2.e119932?term=AVLV2&page=3). The cable was made or designed by "COPARTNER TECHNOLOGY CORP"

Without some information on what is on either end all we can say is that it is some kind of USB cable.